# Combining LaTeX with a "What You See Is What You Get" Word Processor

Tags: editors, software

I'm a mathematics student and I'm getting tired of hand writing all of my assignments so I'm looking to switch to typing. LaTex is of course the best option for typing equations, formulas, etc, but can become cumbersome otherwise for my purposes (Submitting assignments).

What I'm looking for is a combination of a "What You See is What You Get" word processor (ie. Microsoft Word) and LaTeX. What software would you recommend for this purpose? Would using Word with their LaTeX option in their equation editor be a good idea, or is their LaTeX implementation too limited?

Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend more practice using LaTeX. After a while, it's far, far faster than any 'what you see is all you've got' system.

Comment: Have you heard of [Scientific Workplace](https://www.mackichan.com/)? Warning: It's proprietary, it's not cheap, and it hardly ever gets updated.

Comment: I'd suggest writing in markdown with a nice editor (atom, vs code, sublime, typora.io, . . . there are many) and only use latex for the equations. (Or you can try to emulate this guy: https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/)

Comment: I took a look at that article and that's really cool! I never considered using markdown. I think my solution lies there. Thanks @DG'

Comment: You could try `LyX` or `gummi`

Comment: There is also the Microsoft Word plugin [WordTeX](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/twildenh/wordtex/), see also a [video on Youtube](https://youtu.be/jlX_pThh7z8).

Comment: Have you tried LyX (https://www.lyx.org) I have been using it for years. I find it a very good solution between Latex and Word.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you [EqualX](https://equalx.sourceforge.io) as LaTeX equation editor. You type equation and see the result instantly.

In Ubuntu install it using repositories:.

```
sudo apt-get install equalx
```

If you want to edit LaTeX documents: I use [TexStudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) for the documents and [EqualX](https://equalx.sourceforge.io) to type equations; then copy and paste equation in your LaTeX document using [TexStudio](https://www.texstudio.org/).

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is the official account of Docx2LaTeX

We have just launched a Google Docs-add on which combines the power of LaTeX and the ease of Google Docs which is exactly what you want.

Here are the features provided by Docx2LaTeX add-On

1. Directly export to plain **LaTeX** code or **journal templates**.
2. **Add captions** to figures and tables.
3. **Cross-refer** figures,tables and equations.
4. Search the web for **any** article and cite them in the document.
5. View LaTeX compiled to **PDF in real-time**.

**Add-On Link:**
[Docx2LaTeX Google Docs Add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/docx2latex/415272416461)

**Watch Demo:**
[Short Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBVqgzbImug)

Answer (score -1):

Read [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01796-1) and this pretty much sums it up:
“LaTeX is just something that physicists ‘do’,” explains chief editor Andrea Taroni. “Trying to get them to do otherwise is like trying to herd cats.”

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01796-1